# Creating a trigger to count how many times a piece of data has been changed SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am currently writing an SQL trigger that records how many times a piece of data has been changed. It will write it to a column 'PrevAddrNum' in tblCustomer, the trigger executes fine but on testing I got the error message saying "The transaction ended in the trigger the batch has been aborted". Here is my code below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
CREATE TRIGGER PrevAddr ON tblCustomer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF UPDATE(CustomerAddress)
BEGIN
  UPDATE tblCustomer
  SET PrevAddrNum = PrevAddrNum + 1
END
```

Comment: Please note that your trigger can fire when a batch of updates are flushed. The trigger can also fire when only one record in the table gets updated. There can be more than one updated record per trigger event and your code only handles one of them.

Comment: I think there is an error thrown while executing the trigger, so try to add try catch and log errors if exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table has a CustomerID or similar field, you should update only affected records.

```
CREATE TRIGGER PrevAddr ON tblCustomer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN TRY
  UPDATE     tblCustomer
  SET        PrevAddrNum = PrevAddrNum + 1
  FROM       tblCustomer tc
  INNER JOIN deleted 
  ON         tc.CustomerID = deleted.CustomerID
  INNER JOIN inserted 
  ON         tc.CustomerID = inserted.CustomerID
  WHERE      deleted.CustomerAddress <> inserted.CustomerAddress
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- just to get the error 
    -- create a new table ErrorLog and save the errors there
    DECLARE @ErrorMsg VARCHAR(MAX), @ErrorNumber INT, @ErrorProc sysname, ErrorLine INT 

    SELECT @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(), 
           @ErrorProc = ERROR_PROCEDURE(), @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE();

    INSERT INTO ErrorLog (ErrorMsg,  ErrorNumber,  ErrorProc,  ErrorLine)
    VALUES               (@ErrorMsg, @ErrorNumber, @ErrorProc, @ErrorLine)
END CATH
```

Comment: OP - keep in mind that the UPDATE function can be a little confusing. It does not care if the value changed or not, only that the column is in the update statement.

Comment: Yes and you got +1 from me and I removed my old comment. Nicely done.